# How to handle initializing a constant?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to initialize a constant if it doesn't exist and if one is already there then use it. I tried the below and got warnings.

```
User = User || Struct.new(:name) #NameError: uninitialized constant User
User = Struct.new(:name) || User #works (1st time)
```

but this statement will be encountered multiple times, when that happens I get

```
User = Struct.new(:name) || User 

#warning: already initialized constant User
#warning: previous definition of User was here
```

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 User ||= Struct.new(:name)
```

`User = User || Struct.new(:name)` this will not work, as `User` is being checked with conditional operator `||` before defining it. Thus you are getting error as *NameError: uninitialized constant User*. Example

```
# first try that way
X = X || 2 #uninitialized constant X (NameError)
# then comment the above and try below way
X ||= 2
X # => 2
```

`X = X || 2` will not work, as we didn't define it anywhere before using it with `||`.

Comment: Aha, I was under the impression that `a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`

Comment: @Bala No it is not.. I understood that,,